# express-unless on a controller function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know this is a basic question but I am not quite able to figure out how to overcome this condition.

In my api I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var unless = require('express-unless');
var router = express.Router();

// Controllers
var globalController = require('../controllers/global');
router.use(globalController.authorizeToken.unless({path: ['/users', '/pages'], method: 'GET'}));
```

Now I get this error in nodejs.

> TypeError: globalController.authorizeToken.unless is not a function

How do I overcome this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code in `../controllers/global`

Comment: global.js file only has the authorizeToken() method

Comment: Show the code. Otherwise we can't help you. We can't guess what you've written